# How to Use Select2 Multiple Select in Livewire?

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-livewire, livewires

i use select2 in livewire. When adding data, it worked. But when editing the data, and not changing the data in the select option, the previously selected trainer data is all lost.

Here is the code I made.

**Edit.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Courses;

use App\Models\Course;
use App\Models\Trainer;
use Livewire\Component;
use Jantinnerezo\LivewireAlert\LivewireAlert;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use \Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Services\SlugService;

class Edit extends Component
{
    use LivewireAlert;
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $title, $slug, $cover, $video, $link, $method, $format, $duration, $price, $description, $isActive, $meta_keywords, $meta_description, $addon_styles, $addon_scripts, $courseId;
    public $trainer_id;
    public function mount($id)
    {
        $course = Course::findOrFail($id);
        if ($course) {
            $this->courseId         = $course->id;
            $this->trainer_id       = $course->trainer_id;
            $this->title            = $course->title;
            $this->slug             = $course->slug;
            $this->link             = $course->link;
            $this->method           = $course->method;
            $this->format           = $course->format;
            $this->duration         = $course->duration;
            $this->price            = $course->price;
            $this->description      = $course->description;
            $this->isActive         = $course->isActive;
            $this->meta_keywords    = $course->meta_keywords;
            $this->meta_description = $course->meta_description;
            $this->addon_styles     = $course->addon_styles;
            $this->addon_scripts    = $course->addon_scripts;
        }
    }

    public function updatedTitle()
    {
        $this->slug = SlugService::createSlug(Course::class, 'slug', $this->title);
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $course = Course::where('id',$this->courseId)->first();

        $this->validate([
            'title'         => 'required',
            'cover'         => $this->cover ? 'required|image|mimes:png,jpg,webp,jpeg' : '',
            'description'   => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($this->cover) {
            \Storage::delete('public/'.$course->cover);

            $fileName = time().'_'.$this->cover->getClientOriginalName();
            $filePath = $this->cover->storeAs('images/courses', $fileName, 'public');
        } else {
            $filePath = $course->cover ?? null;
        }

        if ($this->video) {

            \Storage::delete('public/'.$course->video);

            $fileName = time().'_'.$this->video->getClientOriginalName();
            $video = $this->cover->storeAs('images/courses', $fileName, 'public');
        } else {
            $video = $course->video ?? null;
        }

        $course->update([
            'title'             => $this->title,
            'slug'              => $this->slug,
            'cover'             => $filePath,
            'video'             => $this->video ? $video : null,
            'link'              => $this->link,
            'method'            => $this->method,
            'format'            => $this->format,
            'duration'          => $this->duration,
            'price'             => $this->price,
            'description'       => $this->description,
            'isActive'          => $this->isActive,
            'meta_keywords'     => $this->meta_keywords,
            'meta_description'  => $this->meta_description,
            'addon_styles'      => $this->addon_styles,
            'addon_scripts'     => $this->addon_scripts
        ]);

        $course->trainers()->sync($this->trainer_id);

        $this->alert('success', 'Data updated successfully.');

        return redirect()->route('courses.index');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.courses.edit',[
            'trainers' => Trainer::where('isActive',true)->get(),
            'course'   => Course::find($this->courseId)
        ])
        ->extends('layouts.app')
        ->section('content');
    }
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```php
<div>
    @section('title', 'Edit Course')
    @section('styles')
    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/tinymce/tinymce.min.js') }}"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        span .selection {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    @endsection
    <!-- ========== title-wrapper start ========== -->
    <div class="title-wrapper pt-30">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="title mb-30">
                    <h2>Edit Course</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end col -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="breadcrumb-wrapper mb-30">
                    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                                <a href="{{ route('home') }}">Dashboard</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                                <a href="{{ route('courses.index') }}">Courses</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
                                Edit Course
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end col -->
        </div>
        <!-- end row -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card-style mb-3">
                <form wire:submit.prevent="update" class="row g-3">
                    <input type="hidden" wire:model="courseId">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="cover" class="form-label">Cover</label><br>
                            @if ($cover)
                            Cover Preview:
                            <div class="card mb-3">
                                <img src="{{ $cover->temporaryUrl() }}" class="w-15 rounded-3">
                            </div>
                            @else
                            <div class="card mb-3">
                                <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$course->cover) }}" class="w-15 rounded-3 img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            @endif
                            <input type="file" wire:model="cover" class="form-control @error('cover') is-invalid @enderror" id="cover">
                            @error('cover')
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </div>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="title" class="form-label">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="title" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" id="title" placeholder="Course Title">
                            @error('title')
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </div>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="slug" class="form-label">Slug</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="slug" class="form-control  @error('slug') is-invalid @enderror" id="slug" placeholder="course-slug">
                            @error('slug')
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </div>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3" wire:ignore>
                            <label for="description" class="form-label">Description</label>
                            <textarea wire:model="description" class="form-control @error('description') is-invalid @enderror" id="description" rows="15"></textarea>
                            @error('description')
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </div>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="video" class="form-label">Video</label>
                            <input type="file" wire:model="video" class="form-control" id="video">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="link" class="form-label">Link</label>
                            <input type="url" wire:model="link" class="form-control" id="link" placeholder="Youtube link">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="method" class="form-label">Method</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="method" class="form-control" id="method" placeholder="Example: online, hybrid">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="format" class="form-label">Format</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="format" class="form-control" id="format" placeholder="Eg: HD Video, Live Concultation">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="duration" class="form-label">Duration</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="duration" class="form-control" id="duration" placeholder="Eg: 3 mounts">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="price" class="form-label">Price</label>
                            <input type="number" wire:model="price" class="form-control @error('price') is-invalid @enderror" id="price" placeholder="Eg: 250000">
                            @error('price')
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </div>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3" wire:ignore>
                            <label for="trainer" class="form-label">Trainer</label>
                            <select multiple="multiple" id="trainer" class="form-select @error('trainer_id') is-invalid @enderror" multiple>
                                @foreach ($trainers as $trainer)
                                <option {{  $course->trainers()->find($trainer->id) ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{ $trainer->id }}">{{ $trainer->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @error('trainer_id')
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {{ $message }}
                            </div>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="meta_keywords" class="form-label">Meta Keywords</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="meta_keywords" class="form-control" id="meta_keywords" placeholder="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="meta_description" class="form-label">Meta Description</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="meta_description" class="form-control" id="meta_description" placeholder="Meta description">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck" wire:model="isActive">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
                            Set active
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="w-100 main-btn primary-btn btn-hover btn-sm" wire:target="update" wire:loading.class="deactive-btn">
                    <span wire:loading.remove wire:target="update">
                    Update
                    </span>
                    <span wire:loading wire:target="update" class="text-center">
                    <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    Loading...
                    </span>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@push('scripts')
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<x-livewire-alert::scripts />
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        menubar: 'file edit view insert format tools table help',
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink autosave codesample lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table toc directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textpattern"
        ],
        toolbar: "restoredraft insertfile undo redo | styleselect fontselect fontsizeselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify codesample | bullist numlist outdent indent toc| link image media",
        setup: function(editor) {
            editor.on('change', function(e) {
                    console.log('the content ', editor.getContent());
                    @this.set('description', editor.getContent());
            });
        }
    });
    
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#trainer').select2();
        $('#trainer').on('change', function (e) {
            var data = $('#trainer').select2("val");
            @this.set('trainer_id', data);
        });
    });

</script>
@endpush
```

How to solve this problem? so that, when I edit the data and without changing the data in select2, the data will not be deleted.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

when editing my modal i load my data to my array as follows;

```
public $selectedOn = [];

public function edit($id){
   $foos = Foo::where('other_id',$id)->get();
   foreach($foos as $foo){
     array_push($this->selectedOn, $foo->id);
   }
   $this->emit('selectLoadOk');

}
```

in my js I do the following;

```
window.livewire.on('selectLoadOk', () =>{
  $('#selectChecklist').trigger('change');
});
```